# Rails Migration doesn't apply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have the following migration:

```
    class MoveInventoryItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def up
        schraenke = ('F'..'J')
        List::Inventory::Item.find_each do |item|
            if schraenke.include?(item.location[0])
                item.location[0] = item.location[0].next.next
                item.save!
            end
        end
      end
   end
```

I am trying to change a variable for specific items.
When I try to output the item after saving, it looks correct. It doesn't show any errors when I run the migration. But obviously it doesn't really get updated, since the old values are still displayed when I run the server.

So my question is: How can a migration not update data?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, up is class level method and you can replace above code with following code, it will update record.

```
class MoveInventoryItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    schraenke = ('F'..'J')
    List::Inventory::Item.find_each do |item|
      if schraenke.include?(item.location[0])
        item.location[0] = item.location[0].next.next
        item.save!
      end
    end
  end

  def self.down
     #put reverse code of above, it will execute when you rollback migration
  end
end
```

Comment: Still doesn't change anything. Could it be that "rake db:upgrade" somehow applies to the wrong database?

Comment: Now, its not updating because, this migration is already run, and its version is stored in schema, the solution is to rake db:rollback, and then run it again